# Difference between range-for and iterator-for

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration

can someone tell me if using the range-for is different from using the iterator-for

```
//I use Array bfor instance, I mean any Iterable container
std::vector<myClass> v;
for(auto&& e : v){
//do stuff
//maybe remove
}

//compared with
for(auto it = v.begin(); it!= v.end; ++it){
//do stuff
//maybe remove
}
```

Are there anomalies in insertion or deletion from the array in the first version compared with the second

Comment: The first one internally is the same as the second one. See [Range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Here you can take a look what it is expanded into internally

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: if you do something with the vector that invalidates iterators then it might be that `it` becomes invalid. This depends on what you actually do in `//do stuff` and `//maybe remove`

Comment: range base for-loop is less bug prone and more handy. From compiler point of view difference is negligible: https://godbolt.org/z/rTcKq7bhb

Answer (score 1):

> can someone tell me if using the range-for is different from using the iterator-for

The range-for is syntactic sugar and can be written using an equivalent traditional for loop with iterators. So, an iterator-for can behave the same as a range-for.

An iterator-for can be different from a range-for if you write it to do something other than what a range-for would do.

For the cases where range-for does what is needed - which is most cases - it is preferred due to its simplicity. It's easy to understand and to write correctly.

> Are there anomalies in insertion or deletion from the array

It isn't possible to insert or delete elements of an array. I suppose that you meant vector.

You must not do operations on vector that you are iterating that would invalidate the current iterator in a range-for loop. Insertion and erasure will invalidate iterators in many cases.

An iterator loop can sometimes be written in a way that isn't identical to a range-for where the invalidation of the iterator is not a problem.

---

That said, you typically shouldn't use either for "maybe remove". You should probably be using the remove-erase idiom.